# QT C++ : Moving several labels at the same time

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have been searching about Threads in QT and ways to process multiple events simultaneously according to their docs, only the main GUI thread can manage GUI related events. So my question is: Is it possible to move multiple labels or objects at the same time during execution? Im trying to create sort of a simulation proyect for school.

What I have right now is: it creates a label everytime I run the function so I need that label to move to a certain spot. Problem is since I need the function executed several times, when it executes again, the previous label stops and moves the new one. After it has completed it goes back to the previous.

Any help is appreciated thanks.

New to asking here and QT in general.

Edit:

Here is what I have of my function:

```
QLabel *cliente = new QLabel(this);
    QPixmap pix("image.jpg");
    cliente->setGeometry(10,50,128,128);
    cliente->setPixmap(pix);
    cliente->show();
    int speed = 100;
    while (cliente->x()<300){
        QTime dieTime = QTime::currentTime().addMSecs(speed);
        while (QTime::currentTime() < dieTime){
            QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100);
        }
        cliente->move(cliente->x()+10,cliente->y());

    }
```

Comment: Of course it's possible to move more than one thing. Would need to see some code to determine what is going wrong in your case.

Comment: Added example of code.

Comment: Using processEvents is asking for trouble (mostly related to keeping methods in your app re-entrant). Use QTimer instead to invoke your method at intervals.

Comment: I added a QTimer to execute the animations every x seconds. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

To handle the movement of widgets it is most advisable to use the [`QPropertyAnimation`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html) class, but if you want to handle parallel group animations it is opportune to use [`QParallelAnimationGroup`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qparallelanimationgroup.html) as shown in the following example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QParallelAnimationGroup>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    w.resize(500, 550);

    QParallelAnimationGroup group;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        QLabel *label = new QLabel(QString("label %1").arg(i), &w);
        QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(label, "pos");
        animation->setDuration(1000);
        animation->setStartValue(QPoint(50*i, 0));
        animation->setEndValue(QPoint(50*i, 50*(i+1)));
        group.addAnimation(animation);
    }
    group.start();
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, I didnt need to group them. But I got what I wanted Thanks so much.

Comment: @P.Zuñiga When you add the group to improve efficiency since everyone uses the same timer, if you do not use it you could have errors if you increase the labes. If my answer was correct, please correct it.